# Reflect visible light transmit infrared light

Tags: optics, reflection, camera

I have a color camera and PIR sensor inside a commercial security camera which records when motion is detected.

I want to hide the security camera behind a 1/2 inch polycarbonate window which reflects the visible spectrum such that the camera is difficult to see but the PIR sensor still detects motion.

Most “mirror like” reflective privacy films also reflect infrared and do not work, I have tried one from Amazon.

Can you suggest a solution?

By transmit I mean passes through the polycarbonate.

The solution does not have to be a mirror, just opaque, to the visible spectrum.

Polycarbonate is a partial tranmitter of infrared used by the PIR sensor but I believe enough infrared passes that the sensor will work.

Comment: Google "cold mirror".

Comment: Thank you photon! A cold mirror would indeed be a good solution, except I have not found an inexpensive source. 3m makes a film but I did not find a price (yet). It is difficult to find a film on Amazon hat isn’t the exact opposite of what I want.

Comment: Can you rearrange your system to put the camera in the reflected path instead of the transmitted one?

Comment: The security camera system contains both the camera and the PIR detector, see https://www.amazon.com/GALAYOU-Security-Cameras-Wireless-Outdoor/dp/B0C2CNCYYC?th=1 They both need to point the same direction.